# Writing Your Own Python Fixtures in Lino Framework

Tags: python

Quick question about instantiation of Instantiator().

http://lino-framework.org/tutorials/dumpy/index.html#the-instantiator-class

I know how to instantiate a class (class_instance = Class() ).

Under 'Writing your Own Python Fixtures' part of Lino Framework's Developer's Guide there is the following 'magic' code (the '.build' is the part I did not understand):

User = Instantiator(
    'users.User',
    'username first_name last_name email').build

Is there a special name for this action?

How does it work? and where do I go to research it?

Comment: Don't assume magic, the tutorial states: "Note that the name User in that file refers to the build method of an Instantiator instance, not to some User model." That is `build`is simply a method in the Instantiator class.

Comment: Moberg, so at the moment we are instantiating with 'User = Instantiator(...)' we are simultaneously calling an Instantiator class attribute with the dot operator '.build'? As opposed to 1. instantiation followed by step 2. call instance attributes?

Comment: Thanks again Moberg. I found the code which I may now look at to determine the mechanics:

Comment: def __call__(self, *values, **kw):
        """Calling an instantiator is the same as callig its :meth:`build`
        method.
        """
        return self.build(*values, **kw)

    def build(self, *values, **kw):
        """Instantiate an object using the default values of this
        instantiator, overridden by the given specified values. The
        number of positional arguments may not exceed the number of
        fieldnames specified when creating this :class:`Instantiator`.
        """

Comment: The solution seemed so obvious at first that I thought there must be some rule or technique that I was unaware of, but infact it was simple afterall. The following code explains it all perfectly: class A(object):       def __init__(self, a):         self.a = a       def Aabb(self, b):         print b         print self.a   y = A('cat').Aabb(15) :: which returns the values 15 cat